# How to compute average of image using Numpy and OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, object-detection

For one of my projects at university, I wish to use Python to select an image based on which is more salient.

To do this I know I will first have to use OpenCv's Saliency Detection. But after the output, where I am left with an image with its saliency map, how do I compute the average saliency in the image? This would allow me to compare two images, and make a definitive decision on which is more salient.

I was advised I could use Numpy for this but unsure of how to actually implement such a thing. (I'm new to Python)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overthinking this. To the computer, an image is just a integer matrix.

To get an average value, compute the mean: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) # this would be your image
m = np.mean(a)
```

Or count all white pixel and divide by the size of the image for a binary image: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 7, 0],[3, 0, 2, 19]]) # your image here
ct = np.count_nonzero(a)
```